# Android TabLayout in Fragment , text missing

Tags: android-tablayout

I write a layout, in one Fragment ,after init TabLayout and ViewPager and tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager), strange problem happened... the texts in TabLayout are missing.
but when I define them in one Activity is OK. 
one of Google bugs?

```
// init with titles and fragments
    adapter = new OrderFragmentAdapter(fragmentManager, titleList, fragments);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(R.color.black_alpha_50, R.color.red_ec5740);
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: Could you put code for OrderFragmentAdapter?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I init the TabLayout in my Fragment and works fine. And make sure you are using the last version of Design Support Library.

```
    String[] categoryNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_home);
    TabPagerAdapter tabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryNames.length; i++) {
        tabPagerAdapter.addFragment(new HomeTabFragment(), categoryNames[i]);
    }        
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Code for `TabPagerAdapter`:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitles.add(title);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for sharing the code.. but tabLayout in my sence still not work, and finally I use TabPageIndicator instead of tabLayout .

Answer (score 2):

Hi I also hits this problem and find out a solution,

android api will auto preset all tab title from your pager adapter when you call tablayout.setupWithViewPager(), so you just need to do this in your pagerAdapter is work!:

```
    String[] title={...};
    ...
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // return your title there
        return getResources().getString(title[position]);
    }
```